# correct spacing when training tesseract

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I use tesseract 3.0.1 on windows 7 64 bit. I train the library with a new language.

My sample data is very well spaced. When I define the coordinates for the box of each character, how important is it for the box to be tightly closed to the character? I use one of the addins and it is much faster to define coarse grained boxes over each character which include some (or a lot of) white space. Of course the box never overlaps other characters.

Answer (score 0):

Practically, it's recommended that you put spaces as similar as they are in the real cases (tests). Then by using [tesseract-box-editor](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-box-editor/) or [jTessBoxEditor](http://vietocr.sourceforge.net/training.html) you will be able to correct the bounding of letters boxes.